# apache's caching (mod_cache) vs squid reverse-proxy caching?

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, squid, reverse-proxy, cache

simple question about an area im not familiar with.

which one is best for caching?

are there other options?

cause i want to be sure which one to use before i learn it. so i dont have to realize afterwards that it was a bad choice.

so would be great if someone could shed a light on this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would choose [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) and [Varnish](http://varnish-cache.org/) over squid at this time for caching static content. Another great and VERY effective way is to cache SQL queries with [memcached](http://memcached.org/)

When you have the chance to have multiple servers, aim for multiple instances of [Cherokee](http://www.cherokee-project.com/), Nginx or Apache along with a MySQL or PosgreSQL and memcached.

Good luck!

Comment: why would i have multiple instanses of web server (apache, nginx etc). isnt it better to just use apache? cause you always have to invest in learning the softwares you are using, and that takes time and energy.

Comment: Take the one you are more familiar with. By multiple instances of them I meant to have multiple http deamon instance running and load balancing requests.

Comment: but i guess they have to be on seperate machines for this to give a performance improvement?

Comment: Yes, 3 machines is the bare minimum, 4+ is optimal. Server1 and Server2 would have Apache+MySQL+memcached. Server3 & 4 would have your load balancer (HAProxy) and static content cache (Varnish)